# find Countrol inside itemTemplate of Gridview without Gridview Events

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

i have a Textbox inside ItemTemplate of a Gridview.. i need to find that textbox without using RowDatabound or any other event of Gridview

**aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_Others" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField >                        
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                        <ItemTemplate >                     
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmp" runat="server" Width=100% Height=22px CssClass="input"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

**aspx.cs**

```
protected void Insert_OtherServices()
    {
        dsJobCardTableAdapters.Select_OtherServiceTableAdapter dsother = new dsJobCardTableAdapters.Select_OtherServiceTableAdapter();
        int count = 0;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv_Others.Rows)
        {
            //string b = (row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as DataBoundLiteralControl).Text;
            //TextBox a = gv_Others.Rows[count].Cells[0].FindControl("txtEmp") as TextBox;
           // string test = a.Text;
            //TextBox other = (TextBox)gv_Others.Rows[count].FindControl("txtEmp");
            TextBox other = (TextBox)gv_Others.TemplateControl.FindControl("txtEmp");
            dsother.Insert_OtherService(other.Text);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

is there any alternative to get the value from textbox which is inside the item template of Gridview

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to find text box values without looping through GridView rows? If is is the case, jQuery/javascript can be used to achieve this.

1. Read all text box values on the client-side. You can find more information on how to do this [here](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/02/find-control-in-aspnet-gridview-jquery.html)
2. Pass these values along with the postback request using a hidden field. Read and use the hidden field value inside your method.